# What was Mercury's Semblance?

Tags: rwby

Volume 6, Chapter 9 of *RWBY* has the following line from Mercury (to Emerald):

> MERCURY: I'm sorry you didn't have a mommy that loved you, but I had a father who hated me. He never went easy on me. Every day of training was a beating. **And when I unlocked my Semblance, he stole it with his. "This is a crutch; this makes you weak!". He told me I could have it back when I was strong. So I got strong, but I never got it back!** I've had to work harder than anyone to get where I am. You may not like it here without Cinder, but I think I'm right where I'm supposed to be.

Googling that question's very title, there are multiple theories about what that Semblance may have been (both pre- and post- the aboverevelation), but they're all speculation. I'm looking for either an official confirmation (or even hints, as long as they're official), or a definite "we won't reveal it" answer, with "official" meaning:

- any creator/voice actor interview/tweet/blog post etc
- any novel or manga chapters
- *RWBY Companion Book* maybe?
- basically anything that has a Rooster Teeth stamp on it.

I'm relatively sure I've never seen anything about Mercury's Semblance other in than the aforementioned episode, but that doesn't mean there isn't a line somewhere. *RWBY*'s crew did something similar with Roman's Semblance, never hinting at it in the show, and revealing on [Tumblr](https://roosterteeth.tumblr.com/post/166078067551/are-there-huntsmenhuntresses-in-the-world-who) that he never unlocked it:

> **Are there huntsmen/huntresses in the world who don’t use semblances?**
>
> Most Huntsmen and Huntresses have discovered their Semblances, but that doesn’t necessarily mean that every warrior has. Roman Torchwick, for instance, never quite found his Semblance. That didn’t stop him from being a formidable fighter, though. -Miles/Kerry